# Make IIS stop running on port 443 for all bound IPs

Tags: iis, networking, multihomed

I have a Win2008 R2 server with IIS installed. The server has multiple IP addresses on the same NIC card. I have a single HTTPS website configured in the IIS Manager. However, IIS seems to always listen to port 443 on all of the IPs, even if I configure the HTTPS website to only be bound to a single IP address.

I'm positive it's IIS because once I do "iisreset/stop", the port becomes available.

The reason I need it is because I'm trying to run another service that needs to listen on port 443 on a specific IP, and IIS isn't letting it.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can accross the same problem i used the following article to fix it. Though, warning i had to restart the system as net stop HTTP crashed and did not come back until i rebooted.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954874

Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK. A Command Prompt window opens.

At the command prompt, type the following command:

`netsh http add iplisten xxx.xxx.x.x`

Note xxx.xxx.x.x represents the IP address that you want to add.

If the IP address is successfully added, you receive the following message:

IP address successfully added

To list the IP address, type the following command after the IP address is added:

`netsh http show iplisten`

The Netsh utility returns the following information:

IP addresses present in the IP listen list: xxx.xxx.x.x

Stop the HTTP service and its dependent services. To do this, type the following command:

`Net stop http`

Restart the HTTP service and its dependent services. To do this, type the following command:

`Net start http`

Restart the W3SVC service. To do this, type the following command:

`Net start w3svc`

Comment: Thanks. worked. For some reason I couldn't do "net stop http", the service wouldn't shut down, so I ended up restarting the box.